# More than 1 update in mysql table at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query in my php code:

```
$diminui = mysql_query("
      UPDATE config_cliente 
      SET saldo = saldo - $price 
      WHERE accountcode='$accountcode'");
```

I'm in dubt about if more than 1 script is running this query at the same time, what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

If your storage database engine is set to InnoDB you should not worry too much...[Read more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) for transaction isolation levels.